# Trying to use a Pycharm generated socket to pull the contents of an HTML file in the same directory

Tags: python, html, sockets

So essentially, I have an HTML file in the same directory as my .py file, which contains the following code:

```
import sys
from socket import *
serverPort = 12500
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print('The server is ready to receive')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        filename = message.split()[1]
        print(filename)
        temp = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = temp.readlines()
        print(outputdata)

        connectionSocket.send(bytes('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n', encoding='UTF-8'))

        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send(bytes('HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND\r\n\r\n', encoding="UTF-8"))
        connectionSocket.close()

    serverSocket.close()
    sys.exit()
```

My goal for this server is that it displays the content of the HTML file when I reference it in a web browser, and gives a 404 error when a non-existent file is found.

**An example input would be:**

http://127.0.0.1:12500/Hello.html

**This would yield this output with my current code:**

The server is ready to receive
/Hello.html

So it is just reading the /Hello.html portion instead of the file. Is there a way to remedy this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the error it shows later? or does it freeze?

Comment: I'm trying to set it where I get a 404 error if the file requested doesn't exist, but as of right now there is no error, it just reads whatever I put into the search bar

Comment: So, only `404` is not working.. but if a file exists, it returns the file?

Comment: It's not returning the file, it is just returning whatever I put inhttp://127.0.0.1:12500/Hello.html. In this example it'd be Hello.html, but if I changed it to http://127.0.0.1:12500/Potato.html  it'd return Potato.html. Not the actual files, just the name Potato.html

Comment: Thats because of the line `print(filename)`, and probably, your code could not find the file, thats why the content is not displayed in terminal, you must have received `404` in browser though(Check in developer tools). If the file exists, try appending absolute path with  `filename` from browser after it received, like `c://path/to/potato.html`

Comment: I think I actually figured it out, I was calling for an html file but the file in question is an htm file. Thanks for your help!